# How to get Android Device Status (Offline or Online) using GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM in my application and push notification is working fine? But I have specific requirement where I (my server) wants to know about Android device status(i.e is online or offline).

Question:
1. Is their any way to check Android Device Status (Offline or Online) by just sending GCM message or something?

1. The only option that came in my mind is “creating” background service in Android device and it will create on-going socket connection with server to update status on pre-defined time interval (5/10 min interval). But pooling @ fix time interval is not the best solution - and that is why looking for other alternatives.

Any pointer or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.